# Запустить удаленный скрипт локально

Tags: bash, ssh

Возможно ли запустить удаленный скрипт на локальной машине через SSH без его копирования на локальную машину?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Есть возможность прочитать удаленный файл и передать вывод локальному интерпретатору:

```
ssh user@host "cat /script.sh" | /bin/bash
```

Выполнение содержимого удаленного скрипта будет выполняться локально.

---

В случае отладки удаленного скрипта на локальном сервере можно добавить ключ `-x`

```
ssh user@host "cat /script.sh" | /bin/bash -x
```

---

Так же в случае необходимости регулярно выполнять скрипты с удаленной машины, можно монтировать директорию со скриптами и запускать их.

Comment: Хочу только добавить, что _в оперативную память_ локальной машины скрипт при этом будет копироваться. Собственно, выполнимость условия, поставленного в вопросе, зависит от того, что́ именно его автор вкладывает в понятие "копирование".

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev, правильное замечание, но скрипт будет выгружен из ОЗУ после выполнения обработки. Без выгрузки в оперативную память, локальный скрипт запустить не получится, единственное различие, что загрузка/выгрузка будет идти построчно. Ввиду этого и рассматривал что автор имел ввиду без копирования в локальную файловую систему.

Comment: Вы правы, я имел ввиду без копирования в локальную файловую систему. Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: @PotroNik, скажите, как в запускаемый скрипт передать параметр(ы)?

Comment: @d7d1cd С параметром все сложнее, так как происходит чтение из файла, нужно производить подстановку параметров налету: `ssh user@host "sed 's/\$1/=param1/g;s/\$2/=param2/g' /script.sh" | /bin/bash` Вероятнее всего стоит рассмотреть вариант с монтированием удаленной файловой системы.